# How to download Windows Files on Debian 10 Linux? (.Exe)

Tags: linux, terminal

I want to download a game launcher called "DDtank New Era Launcher" on my chromebook but there's no Linux download available.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way - install „playonlinux” (gui) or „wine” (cli) and run app from there. Should work :) . If doesn’t there is a second way - download „virtualbox” or any other emulator and run windows from .iso file (virtualbox should even support drag&drop method, i didn’t yet tested with windows but anyways it should work).

Comment: I don't know of a Virtualbox package that can run on Chrome OS, which is not a general purpose Linux.

Comment: ? Installing from tar.gz doesn't work?

Comment: You mean VirtualBox-6.1.20-143896-Linux_amd64.run? Even if it's an installer compiled for the least common denominator, you will encounter one problem when attempting to install traditional Linux software directly on Chrome OS: you have no root/sudo privileges and you have no terminal. Yes there is a shell (crosh) but unless you enable developer mode—which voids your warranty—you won't get a standard shell, only a shell for getting some information. Think of it like unrooted Android. Crostini gives you Debian inside an LXD container inside of a VM, similar to WSL2. Chrome OS != "Linux", but ok

Comment: Ah, okay. There is no way to normally download wine and try with it? ( maybe i dont have chromeos but i think it should be because its even on macos)

Comment: You were initially limited to Chrome extensions. There [ScummVM](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/scummvm/ddjnneijgokkhfkjlnodlpmjdamlkbmi) and [DOSBox](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dosbox-for-google-chrome/jhceknlmaggijlkkcemdaghpniimajhd) exist, I haven't looked for Wine. A new coming to Chrome thing is Parallels, but I don't know if and how there will be something like this available anytime soon outside of enterprise environments: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vrGpvF5wSfg That's all I know. Chrome OS is an appliance and they've been working on supporting VMs.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried it yet on my Chromebooks but [Bottles](https://flathub.org/apps/details/com.usebottles.bottles) looks interesting and should work fine once you have flatpak installed and flathub set up.

via https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l_7gcCngzVY